# JavaScript rendering [object Object] in page rather than data

Tags: javascript, excel, ag-grid

Hi all I am using the following code to render an excel document in an AG Grid

```js
  function populateGrid(workbook) {
    // our data is in the first sheet
    var firstSheetName = workbook.SheetNames[0];
    var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[firstSheetName];
  
    // we expect the following columns to be present
    var columns = {
      A: 'BQ Id',
      B: 'Ref:-',
      C: '',
      D: 'Description',
      E: 'Qty',
      F: 'Unit',
      G: 'Rate',
      H: 'Amount',
    };
  
    var rowData = [];
  
    // start at the 2nd row - the first row are the headers
    var rowIndex = 2;
  
    // iterate over the worksheet pulling out the columns we're expecting
    while (worksheet['A' + rowIndex]) {
      var row = {};
      Object.keys(columns).forEach(function (column) {
        row[columns[column]] = worksheet[column + rowIndex].w;
      });
  
      rowData.push(row);
  
      rowIndex++;
    }
  
    // finally, set the imported rowData into the grid
    gridOptions.api.setRowData(rowData);
  }
```

This is taken from the AG Grid docs https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/excel-import/ however when I run this code I get the following:
[Output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shI3X.png) How can I get the code to render the actual data?

Comment: Please reproduce your issue using a plunkr from: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/excel-import/#example-excel-import

Comment: Using the olympic-data spreadsheet dataset as used in the example the program loads as expected however when using any of my own spreadsheets it renders as [object Object] or using `row[columns[column]] = worksheet[column + rowIndex].w;` produces the error `excel:873 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'w')`